# sort elements in jQuery object

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="myClass">1</div>
<div class="myClass">2</div>
<div class="myClass">3</div>
<div class="myClass">4</div>
<div class="myClass">5</div>
<div class="myClass">6</div>

var $myClass = $('.myClass');
$myClass.eq(0).text() //returns '1'
$myClass.eq(4).text() //returns '5'
$myClass.eq(5).text() //returns '6'
```

What I want to do is reorder the objects in jQuery manually.

```
//fantasy command reversing
$myClass.eqSorter([5,4,3,2,1,0]);
$myClass.eq(0).text() //returns '6'
$myClass.eq(5).text() //returns '1'
```

What I really want is to allow a fully custom order input

```
//fantasy command custom ordering
$myClass.eqSorter([3,5,4,2,0,1]);
$myClass.eq(0).text() //returns '4'
$myClass.eq(5).text() //returns '2'
```

Now I've looked at basic ways of doing this like `.sort` as a part of javascript, but `.sort` takes a dynamic argument the compares things, and does not allow for a fully custom order. I also looked at making a new blank jquery object that I could pass elements into like this `$newObjectVar.eq(0) = $myClass.eq(3);` for example. But as of yet I have not found a way to make a blank jQuery object like this.

Comment: Think of the jQuery object as an array. How would you sort an array in that order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a custom method like this that would reorder the existing DOM elements in the jQuery object.  One issue is that many operations on jQuery objects sort them into DOM order so they may not stay in this order if you carry out other operations on the jQuery object.

```
jQuery.fn.eqSorter = function(array) {
    // get copy of DOM element array
    var copy = this.toArray();
    // don't exceed bounds of arrays
    var len = Math.min(array.length, copy.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var index = array[i];
        // make sure incoming index is within bounds of DOM object array
        if (index < copy.length) {         
            // put the index item into the i location
            this[i] = copy[index];
        }
    }
    return this;
}

$myClass.eqSorter([5,4,3,2,1,0]);
```

---

After some more thinking, here's another way of doing things that is also a lot more robust as it prevents dups and holes even if the array passed in has errors in it.  The result will be only the elements that match the indexes in the passed in array.  Any dups or indexes out of range will be ignored.

The jQuery way of doing things is generally not to change the DOM elements in a given jQuery object, but to modify the existing jQuery object into a new jQuery object.  To implement it that way, with the added robustness you could do this:

```
jQuery.fn.eqSorter = function(array) {
    var elems = [], doneIndexes = {}, index;
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        index = array[i];
        // if the index is not out of range and it's not a dup, 
        // then get the corresponding DOM element from the jQuery object
        // and put it into the new array
        if (!doneIndexes[index] && index < this.length && index >= 0) {
            elems.push(this[index]);
            doneIndexes[index] = true;
        }
    }
    return this.pushStack(elems, "eqSorter", arguments);
}

var $myOrderedObj = $myClass.eqSorter([5,4,3,2,1,0]);
```

This has the following behavior:

- Any duplicate indexes in the passed in array are ignored (only the first one is processed)
- Any indexes that are out of range are ignored
- Any DOM elements in the initial jQuery object that are not referenced by an index will not appear in the result
- This method returns a new jQuery object and can be used with `.end()`

There's a working testbed here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DPhc9/

Comment: If `array` is not comprehensive then I think the jQuery object could (and most likely would) end up with missing elements and duplicates. Needs testing.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - yes that is true.  The OP did not specify what should happen in that case (truncate to only the indexes specified? put unused objects at end? ignore out of range indexes?  reject the whole operation? etc...).  With a proper specification for what should happen in that case, the code could be extended to handle whatever was specified.

Comment: I wonder if a fairly simple mod would make `.eqSorter` more robust - namely to empty out the original jQuery object before copying elements back in from `copy`.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - I added a new version to my answer that is fully robust against dups, out of range indexes, insufficient indexes.

Comment: Looks cool @jfriend00. I'm sure that's a better behaviour for a badly formed `array` than v1. `.pushStack()` is definitely the way to go - makes the operation reversible with `.end()`. Top code.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - and the funny part is that the more robust version is the same number of lines of code as the original.